# Function only printing last 2 key:value pairs of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a function that takes a dictionary as a parameter. The dictionary is made up of a key which is a last name and a value is a list of first names.

The function should return a new dictionary where each key is the first letter of the key in the parameter, and the value is the number of items in the value of the parameter

Example

```
names = {"Stark": ["Ned", "Robb", "Sansa"], "Snow" : ["Jon"], "Lannister": ["Jaime", "Cersei", "Tywin"]}

{"S" : 3, "S" : 1,  "L": 3}
```

The function I've written is only printing '{'S': 1, 'L': 3}' the last 2 key, value pairs in the dictionary but I want {'S': 3, 'S': 1, 'L': 3} printed

```
def count_first_letter(names):
     beginning = []
     last = []
     for element, number in names.items():
       amount = len(number)
       first = element[0]
       last.append(amount)
       beginning.append(first)
    
     new = {key:value for key, value in zip(beginning, last)}
    
    
     return new
    
    
    
    print(count_first_letter({"Stark": ["Ned", "Robb", "Sansa"], "Snow": ["Jon"], "Lannister": ["Jaime", "Cersei", "Tywin"]}))

'{'S': 1, 'L': 3}'
```

Comment: Your required output is impossible. Dict keys must be unique. Even if it was possible, it would have been useless. How would you tell the difference between `'S'` and `'S'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary keys are getting overridden, so `'S': 3` is getting overridden by `'S': 1` because a dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys

To fix your problem, you would need to put them in a list like this:

```
new = [(key,value) for key, value in zip(beginning, last)]
```

output:

```
[('S', 3), ('S', 1), ('L', 3)]
```

Comment: Why does 'new = [(key,value) for key, value in zip(beginning, last)]' stop the keys being overridden ?

Comment: Because converting the zipped list to a dictionary will cause the dictionary to use a single value for each key, because a dictionary cannot contain the same key so something like ```{"S" : 3, "S" : 1,  "L": 3}``` is impossible for a dictionary to contain. In your example, the ```'S':1``` field replaces the value where 'S' is already set, which is 3, so it replaces it with 1. If you run your code multiple times, you will see the output is actually random, so sometimes you will get ```{'S':3, 'L':3}``` instead. Using a list would not cause this problem

Comment: To understand how dictionaries work, I would read this: 

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Because 2 of your last names start with same letter: Stark, Snow. Thus, overwriting each other as dictionary keys are unique.